# Appropriate GRANT permissions only to list tables and structure in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a MySQL user for my data catalog so it can extract metadata from my databases.

I don't want to grant DML permissions but only limit the user to query `information_schema` for databases, tables, columns and views.

I couldn't find an appropriate permission [on the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) as it seems to require `SELECT` to be granted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema-introduction.html#information-schema-privileges says:

> For most INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables, each MySQL user has the right to access them, but can see only the rows in the tables that correspond to objects for which the user has the proper access privileges.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html says:

> Shows the CREATE TABLE statement that creates the named table. To use this statement, you must have some privilege for the table.

MySQL doesn't have a distinct privilege for viewing metadata about a table without having some other DML privilege on that table.